# Pyramid shaped observatories

Tags: observatory

There are some pyramid shaped observatories around the world, like the [Solar Lab Pyramid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohqzv.jpg) in the Canary Islands or [The Pyramid International Laboratory](http://evk2cnr.org/cms/en/evk2cnr_committee/pyramid) in Nepal.

I was wondering, why a pyramid? Because of its relative stability, or is there something else?

---

**below:** [Solar Lab Pyramid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohqzv.jpg) in the Canary Islands.

[image: Solar Lab Pyramid Canary Islands]

**below:** [The Pyramid International Laboratory](http://evk2cnr.org/cms/en/evk2cnr_committee/pyramid) in Nepal.

[image: Pyramid International Laboratory Nepal]

Comment: I'd be surprised if it is anything but architectural art work.

Comment: Note that *I don't think* these are astronomical observatories in the usual sense, supporting one large telescope. (Nice looking buildings by the way.)

Comment: @LocalFluff surprise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are solar observatories, and so have different requirements from conventional telescopes.

The sloping sides may allow for smoother air flow around the building, as heating during the day causes air to rise, which affects the resolution of the image. Also the pyramid is structurally strong (useful when you have a building on top of a mountain) and attractive, echoing she shape of the mountains. The Nepali observatory uses the flat walls to mount photovoltaic cells.